# Should you assign „0“ to a count variable that is not applicable?

Tags: feature-selection, experiment-design, feature-engineering, medicine, variable

I am designing a retrospective study in the field of oral and mandibular reconstruction. I am struggling with the interdependence of the following two variables and would greatly appreciate any input as I have come across this issue numerous times before:

**Transplant donor site:**

- Fibula (bony)
- Pelvis (bony)
- Scapula (bony)
- Radial forearm (non-bony)
- Latissimus (non-bony)
- Anterolateral thigh (non-bony)

**Number of bony segments transplanted:**
*Only applicable for the three bony donor sites.*

- Can be 1, 2, 3 or 4.

I am struggling to decide between the following 2 options:

- Answer the count variable only if the transplant has a bony part (from the first three donor sites) and leave it NA in any other case
- Answer the count variable regardless of wether bone was transplanted or not. If no bone was transplanted, answer “0”

The second approach has the advantage of being able to use the count variable for every patient thus providing more detail.
The disadvantage I see is that the information is redundant. If the donor site was non-bony the count will always be “0”. Is this a valid concern?

Comment: Isn't this really a categorical variable with four levels? Otherwise, one could always relabel the values of count variable in the model 0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, etc.

Comment: `If the donor site was non-bony the count will always be “0”. Is this a valid concern?` Shouldn’t it be the case that the amount of bone is recorded as zero when no bone is involved? I’m not following the concern. Does it have something to do with a possible relationship between two predictor variables?

Comment: I agree. My concern was that the relationship between patients receiving an increasing amount of bone segments is vastly different than to patients not receiving bone at all. Assuming that there is a linear correlation between the number of segments and complications, adding “0 segments” would dilute the linearity of the relationship of the two variables.

Comment: I think you'll have to expand on the model you are trying to build for us to give a good answer to this question...

Comment: What are you trying to find out?

Comment: I think my question can really be broken down to this: Should you first use a boolean variable to assess wether a feature is applicable at all, before further gathering detail on that specific feature? @PeterFlom

Comment: Using a simple analogy of a marathon, is there a benefit to first asking `Did the runner participate?` and only if `True` further specify e.g. `How much distance did he/she run?`or can that information be queried in one variable by adding the option to choose `Did not participate` in the variable for the distance completed (`10 km, 20 km, 30 km, did not participate`) @Dave